# Why is my segue causing an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" NSInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard, unrecognized-selector

Trying to move from my first ViewController to my second ViewController (both using same storyboard), using a segue. My first ViewController has two buttons, one that says "Male", one that says "Female" (I know, not everyone associates with one of these two), and I want either, once clicked, to move to the second ViewController. I drag/dropped the button into my code to get the following:

```
@IBAction func femaleButton(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    Globals.onboardingList.append("girl")
    print("it's a girl!")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "femaleSegue", sender: self)
}
```

The Male button is identical. Using printlines I know that the program works until the "performSegue" line. I added visual segues and put their identifiers as maleSegue and femaleSegue. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[Train.SecondVC 
_setViewDelegateContentOverlayInsetsAreClean:]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance 0x7fc482d02b00'
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: It looks like the app crashes in the second vc. Can you add code in second vc?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("got to second page")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

Comment: only the original stuff....with a printline in viewDidLoad(), that never shows up

Comment: Check the class assigned in interface builder for the second view controller

Comment: Can it be a swift file or does it have to be a cocoa touch class? I think that might be my issue

Comment: Do you have the second view controller or any views in that view controller's view hierarchy that has a view with class that is not a subclass of UIView, then that might be the issue.

Comment: Were you able to fix?

Comment: No, my first viewController uses custom class ViewController.swift, and my second viewController uses custom class SecondVC.swift, the specific views just have the greyed-out "UIView"

Comment: haven't been able to fix

Comment: Thanks for your help, fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure the real problem as i believe you are not using the right identifier or made the segue connection from storyboard from the wrong view controller, however to make sure, please make one segue ctr + click on the button and drag it to the second screen and comment your action, if this works then remove that segue and the previous two segues and do it again but focus this time :)

Comment: what do you mean, "and comment your action?" I tried deleting the segue but it's still causing the same error...What is the exact order to do things? Control click from button-->view controller 2, then in my code, drag button press and then add code "perform segue"?

Comment: comment your action, i mean the button action implementation , the perform segue ,
just comment that line and ctr + click and drag from the button to the second screen and select the segue , this will automatically perform the segue on click

Comment: Yes, I'm not really sure how, but this resolved it. THANKS! Do you not have to use performSegue() in the code itself?

Comment: No, you must use performSegue() if you have some conditions 
that will call different segues , so you need to make what you did but right this time, i can't figure what did you do wrong but you can watch a video about it or something, and please if you found the answer helpful vote it up ^_^

Comment: I did vote it up, but it doesn't show up because my account isn't old enough!!

Comment: it doesn't matter ^__^

Answer (score 4):

In my case I got this error because I had made a custom ViewController class and mistakenly assigned it to the View in the Storyboard instead of the ViewController. Check your Storyboard View and ViewControllers for custom classes and make sure you've set them appropriately.