# unrecognized selector sent to instance (_setViewDelegateContentOverlayInsetsAreClean)

Tags: objective-c, unrecognized-selector

It looks like there is a lot of way to get this error. I couldn't find any solution that worked in my case. The difference with most thread with the same error, is that the view that throw the error is my initial view and not called by a segue.

Here Is my error log:

```
Tabuleo[87837:3767493] -[loginViewController _setViewDelegateContentOverlayInsetsAreClean:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb513d104e0
2018-07-03 13:37:25.365645+0200 Tabuleo[87837:3767493]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[loginViewController _setViewDelegateContentOverlayInsetsAreClean:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I can't figure out by myself where it comes from because in my code I don't have any method called "_setViewDelegateContentOverlayInsetsAreClean".

At this point I don't have any clue and I read almost all post related to that.

My code is about 350 lines so I put a link to download it if it helps.

[loginViewController.m](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8v3u4237utwnfw3/loginViewController.m)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my segue causing an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" NSInvalidArgumentException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502525/why-is-my-segue-causing-an-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-nsinvalidarg)

Comment: I've already read this thread the thing is this error is happening on my initial view.. Still I'm using segue to navigate from this view to another. Can this mean that there is still a segue issue ?

Comment: What kind of segue did you put?

Comment: My initial view is the loginViewController and from this view there is a show segue that goes to another view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally.
I don't know exactly where it was messed up but redo every link of my elements in my storyboard for this view finally ended up working !
So if that happen just redo your links from storyboard to .h file.